# Continuity checking in C# diagrams

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a requirement where I've to draw a big circle of say radius R and n small circles in it of radius r (<=R) randomly. Now, I want to check if these small circles are all connected using some method. Is there an easy way where different colors can be used to draw and then check if all the circles of the same color touch? I'm open to any programming language!

New:
Thanks! Sure, I've tried to solve it. My first solution was to find the distances between centers of smaller circles. And doing this repeatedly until to form a list of connected circles. But the problem here is there is chance of evaluating multiple smaller network of circles and not that all the small circles are connected. I can maintain one bit-array per small circle to track it's connection to every other circle. But, such a method just explodes when the small circles are in hundreds, which is my requirement. Every path from every circle to every other has to be maintained. So, I dropped this idea.

Next, I came up with an idea where I would draw the smaller circles with a different color and try to find the connectivity using some way (I don't know how) to check if the same colors are contiguous in space on a drawing. I wanted to find out if there was a standard way to detect color continuity.

I couldn't attach the picture for the same, but I hope I make the problem clear?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try and show what you have tried/research you have done - it's not a great idea to get others to try and do your homework.

Comment: Also, you know C++ and C# are completely different languages? Considering the rest, I guess the C++ tag was simply wrong.

Comment: Two circles overlap iff the distance between their centers is not larger than the sum of their radii. The distance between their centers can be calculated with Pythagorean theorem. Up to this point, no drawing is needed.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with an algorithm which would convert this space problem into a graph problem based on the connectivity of smaller circles. Once a graph is created, like an adjacency matrix, then it's quite straight forward to search or check if all nodes are connected. So, I guess that solves the problem. Thanks anyways!